# Can't choose Execution on all nodes in Configure Processor in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a cluster of 3 apache nifi nodes. Like this photo below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXPUx.png)

But when I config the processor, I can only choose to run on primary node, the "all nodes" option is blurred like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyOh6.png)

Here are my processors and its flow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijG86.png)
Only the QueryDatabaseTable processor have this error, the PutDatabaseRecord processor on the other hand, can choose to execute on all nodes

How can I change "Execution" to "all nodes" for the QueryDatabaseTable processor ?

I tried to delete the processor and create a new one but still have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional, if you ran QueryDatabaseTable on every node, they would each pull the same data and you'd be dealing with the same rows on every node. Can you describe your use case? The idea behind this restriction is that you run the QueryDatabaseTable on one node and then distribute the FlowFiles among the nodes via a Remote Process Group or (preferably) a Load-Balanced Connection (in later versions of NiFi).

If you want to parallelize the fetching, take a look at GenerateTableFetch rather than QueryDatabaseTable, you can distribute the SQL statements to all the nodes to do the fetching with ExecuteSQL(Record) in parallel.